# Refresh parent page upon closing child with JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to close the child tab and refresh the parent tab scenario.

**script**

```
function closeRefresh(){      
        window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
        window.top.close();
       }
```

This script is working fine in Chrome but it is not working in IE .In IE the child tab itself refreshing and loading the parent page in the child tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh the parent window after opening a pop up window from inline page?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46192/how-to-refresh-the-parent-window-after-opening-a-pop-up-window-from-inline-page)

Comment: the same code i used still it is not working in IE as expected ,

Answer (score 1):

For IE `window.opener` will not work you have to use `window.showModalDialog`. You can pass parameters from parent to child as well as child to parent. `window.showModalDialog` return a value to parent based upon that you can refresh the parent. `window.showModalDialog` will work for IE and FF you have to handle in JavaScript accordingly. Here is a parent child example.

**parent.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function openWindow() {
   var myArguments = new Object();
   myArguments.bgcolor = document.all.myColor.value;
   var dialogResults = window.showModalDialog("child.html", myArguments, '');
   if ( (dialogResults != undefined) && (dialogResults != '') && (dialogResults != false) ){
      alert(dialogResults);
      window.location=window.location;
   }
} 
</script>
<select id="myColor">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<button onclick="openWindow();">Open window</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    var bgColor = oMyObject.bgcolor;    
    function closeWindow() {
        alert(bgColor);
        window.returnValue = 'Refresh';
        window.close();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onClick="closeWindow();">Click here to close the window</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the console? If that's the case then you will need to look at the Console Integration Toolkit.

Here's a link to the example from Salesforce https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_sample_vf.htm

Make sure you pay particular attention to their best practices: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_best_practices.htm

If you aren't using Console then try this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46195/11369 .

Comment: Iam not using console ...